# Time necessary for making a connection flying Easyjet from Bristol, UK to Amsterdam and connecting on Delta Airlines to Detroit, MI, US

Tags: short-connections, ams, connecting-flights

How much time should I allow for attempting to make a connecting flight departing Bristol, UK on Easyjet and making my connecting flight on Delta Airlines to Detroit, MI, USA at Amsterdam Schiphol Airport? I would have approximately one hour and ten minutes should I attempt to connect with the earliest possible connecting flight with Delta. If I do not make that connection, I would have at least an additional two and a half hour wait for the next available flight.  What do you think my chances are of making that first connection?

Comment: Are both flights booked on a single ticket, or were they booked separately?

Comment: If your on a short connection you could consider using the Gatwick connect service: https://www.gatwickairport.com/faqs/flight-connections/ which is basically insurance by the airport so that you will be put on the next flight, even if you have two separate tickets.

Comment: @skifans:  That's a nice service, but how is it relevant to a connection via Schiphol?

Comment: @Michael Seifert It isn't, I've clearly just ended up confused somehow.

Comment: I'd budget 4 hours AT LEAST. 6 hours would be safer

Comment: @JimMacKenzie There is no way you could have a single ticket with EasyJet + Delta.  EasyJet don't do that sort of thing.

Comment: If you haven't visited Amsterdam yet use the opportunity and plan to spend a day in Amsterdam.

Comment: I'm the guy who books int-int offline at Miami in 70 minutes. (I have a collection of the orange "Express Connection" envelopes somewhere.) And even I think your plan is ridiculously optimistic.

Comment: Why even bother going to Amsterdam?  KLM has a codeshare with Delta leaving from Heathrow direct to Detroit.  Get the train or bus from Bristol to Heathrow.

Answer (score 28):

This is a bad plan. EasyJet and Delta do not interline, so you'd be purchasing two separate tickets. When you do this, you are responsible for arranging your own connection, not the airlines. If you have checked baggage, you'll have to go through immigration, baggage claim, and customs, then go to the Delta counter and check them in before proceeding through security and exit immigration. Since the check-in counter and boarding door close before the departure time, this is not practical to do in 1:10 even if everything is on time.

Because you've arranged your own connection, Delta is not responsible if you miss your flight (even if the easyJet flight is delayed) and could require you to pay a considerable amount of money for a ticket on a later flight and/or incur the costs of a lengthy delay.

Since you are, as your username notes, a "first time traveler in Europe," I'd book this all on one ticket with another airline, even if it costs more, so you don't have to worry about your connection. If you must have two separate tickets, I'd allow several hours to give yourself a cushion for at least some delays; you could consider giving yourself a very long layover and taking the train into Amsterdam for a look-around, as it's a fast and easy trip into the city.

Comment: Plus, check-in may even close before having completed immigration and customs, or even before the arriving aircraft docks at the gate.

Comment: 1 hour 10 minutes at Schiphol is really pushing it even if everything goes perfectly. It is a HUGE airport and you could easily eat most of that picking up bags and hoofing it to the connecting flight. Remember the gate will close at least 15 minutes before takeoff and you will have at least one (more likely two) sets of passport control to negotiate (Plus security). Also baggage check for the Delta leg will close probably 45 minutes before the flight. I would not expect this to work.

Comment: @DanMills: It's indeed two times passport control, but that's not the main delay. The real problem is security, as you have to physically leave the controlled area in order to pick up your luggage and check-in with Delta. And Schiphol is known to be severely understaffed.

Comment: @MSalters That's news to me. Schiphol is not so bad, certainly for an airport this size.

Comment: @Relaxed Since they switched to centralized security it has really gone down the pan.

Answer (score 12):

EasyJet does not do connections and does not do 'one ticket' with other airlines or even their own.

So you are on your own if the EasyJet flight is delayed.

I have flown a few times on this route in the last few years and my record of delays runs from nothing to almost 3 hours. With 2 out of 6 journeys with a delay of two to almost three hours.
One time I had an hour wait to pass through passport control in Amsterdam, just because it was busy and there were problems with the automated passport control system.
Based on that I would not book an ongoing flight with 3 hours or less in Amsterdam.

If you can, consider the KLM flights from Bristol, as that company does do 'one ticket' or 'guarantied connection' and you can stay airside in Amsterdam when you have arranged your right tickets.

So it depends on how important your ongoing journey is. If you have to fly EasyJet, consider to fly to Amsterdam a day ahead of time. Or get a single ticket Bristol - Detroit with KLM and Delta.

Comment: EasyJet has [some worldwide connections out of Gatwick now](http://www.easyjet.com/en/worldwide) as a fairly new offering, but that wouldn't apply in this case.

Comment: @ZachLipton In ticketing parlance, a connection is formally between two successive flights on the same ticket (or in the same ticket booklet). That is what is meant if people say "low cost carriers do not participate in connections": anything else is two separate journeys, perhaps with little intervening delay. Since EasyJet is not an IATA member it is not obliged to use the industry standard wording in its publications. Even English courts have found the reasoning suspect when the airline bundles two tickets as one journey. But that is the background for the "this is not a connection" advice.

Answer (score 3):

You have no chance whatsoever of making that connection. Delta will close check-in for the Detroit flight an hour before departure so, if your EasyJet flight is on time, you will have ten minutes to get through immigration, collect your bags and check them in again. In ten minutes, I doubt you'll manage more than getting to the immigration queue.

You mention that, if you miss your connection, there's another flight in two-and-a-half hours. That honestly doesn't help you very much at all. First, that flight is quite likely to be completely full. Second, even if it isn't, you'll have to pay to change your ticket.  It is your responsibility to arrive at the airport on time and if you fail to do that, the airline is under no obligation to put you on another flight for free. As far as the airline (in this case, Delta but this applies whenever you have a flight on a separate ticket) is concerned, another airline's plane being late is just the same as the train being late or you setting off too late in your car.

If you haven't already bought these tickets, I strongly recommend that you change your plans. Buy *one* ticket that covers your whole journey. In that case, you must get to the first airport on time but, then, if a flight on that ticket is delayed, they will put you on the next available flight because it was their fault you missed the connection, rather than yours. Furthermore, with one ticket, your bags will automatically be checked through to your destination and you won't have to go through immigration at Amsterdam.

If you have already bought the ticket from Amsterdam to Detroit, you need to allow much more than an hour for your connection. I would allow at least three hours: you're recommended to check in at least two hours before departure and this allows an extra hour in case your incoming flight is delayed.